# Associative Array with keys from an Array of Strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to form a word list in Javascript, whereby each word is a key in the dictionary and the value is true. My program takes a word and and checks whether the word is a valid word in the list or not. The list of words is stored in a text file where words are separated by new line. I scan these words as a string and split the string to obtain an array of strings which consist of all words. Now I am unable to form the associative array from this array. Here is my code:

```
var dict={};
var words;
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
words=xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n");
for ( var i = 0; i < words.length; i++ ) {
       dict[words[i]] = true; //This Section of Code not working
}
}
 }


xmlhttp.open("GET","twl06.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function check(str)
{
if(dict[str])
    alert("Correct");
else
    alert("Incorrect");
}
```

After doing a lot of tweaks with the code I have figured out that somehow the assosciative array is not being formed.

Here is the link to my full html/JS code:  https://pastebin.com/2jwMcBfA

Comment: How do you know that `dict[words[i]] = true;` "does not work" and what do you even mean by *does not work*? The line looks correct, assuming that `words` does indeed contain a list of words. Do you get any error? You have to provide more information. Do some basic debugging, inspect the values of the variables, etc.

Comment: @FelixKling Kling :The words array is correctly being generated as I can access the individual elements by using a subscript notation. Now my first word is "AA" . If i do words[0], I get "AA". But if i do dict["AA"] after running the above function, I get undefined.

Comment: Maybe you are accessing `dict` *before* it was populated. Ajax is asynchronous, so the code following your `loadXMLDoc()` call is run *before* the `onreadystatechange` handler is executed. Another problem could be that the words actually have leading or trailing white spaces. Make sure you use `console.log` to inspect the data and not `alert`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Words do not have a trailing or leading space i checked that. Also if I replace the for loop for dict with simply dict["AA"]=true in loadXMLDoc function,then the function check works for "AA"

Comment: Well, without a demo or the actually data is not much we can say.

Comment: @FelixKling Can I email you both the text file and the code ?

Comment: I suggest you upload it somehwere like [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), so that everyone can have a look.

Comment: @FelixKling- I have edited my question and included both my code and the text file containing the words. Kindly help me out.
Thanx

Comment: When you split I would sugest that you split on `\r\n` not only `\n` that will leave a `\r` trailing

Comment: @DavidLaberge : Thanx a lot that was the problem......I changed that and now everything is working smoothly...Thanx a lot :-)

Comment: Abhinav: That's what I meant by trailing whitespaces. @David: You should write this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you split I would sugest that you split on `\r\n` not only `\n` that will leave a `\r` trailing

Answer (score -1):

Unless words[i] is an integer, you cannot use it as index for another array (JavaScript does not have associative arrays).

Best workaround is to do dict[words.indexOf(i)] /(edited)/ or some other way to convert words[i] to integer.

Comment: The Problem has been solved by the suggestion of David Labarge

Comment: `dict` is an object, `words[i]` will be a string. It's perfectly fine to set properties this way. `indexOf` is a function that does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should have been dict[words.idexOf(i)]. And although you can use a string as index, it's not quite easy to parse the entire array later (indexOf('string') returns -1). 

indexOf DOES exist: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Again, `dict` is an **object** not an array. Objects don't have an `indexOf` method. It would not make sense, has properties have no order. The whole purpose of using an object here is to have a fast lookup of words. Of course you should never use string indexes with an array, but that is not the case here.